# How to perform multiple actions and click on the link with text as Member Login on the url http://www.spicejet.com/ through selenium-webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

[image]

I tried the below code but it is not mouse hovering and clicking on 'Member login'

```
WebElement lgn = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_HyperLinkLogin"));
WebElement ssm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'SpiceCash/SpiceClub Members')]"));
WebElement cgm = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Member Login')]"));
Actions a1 = new Actions(driver);
a1.moveToElement(lgn).moveToElement(ssm).moveToElement(cgm).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: unable to click on 'member login'

Comment: You need to give more details. What exactly happens when you run this code? if you have any errors you need to post the stack trace. You also need to post the relevant html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invoke `click()` on the element with text as **Member login**, first you have to *Mouse Hover* over the element with text as **LOGIN / SIGNUP**, then *Mouse Hover* over the element with text as **SpiceCash/SpiceClub Members** then induce *WebDriverWait* for the element with text as **Member Login** to be clickable and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class Spicejet_member_login {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("http://www.spicejet.com/");
          new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a.link#ctl00_HyperLinkLogin")))).build().perform();
          new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[@class='hide-mobile']/a[contains(.,'SpiceCash/SpiceClub Members')]")))).build().perform();
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='hide-mobile']//ul/li/a[@href='https://book.spicejet.com/Login.aspx' and contains(.,'Member Login')]"))).click();
      }
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spicejet_member_login]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add waits between your moveToElement() calls

`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver(), 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element))`

where the "element" is your menu that should appear on hover.

Or you can use ready solution [Selenide](http://selenide.org/index.html) framework which is built on top of the Selenium and has built in hover method and waits which help to handle page dynamics
By this [link](http://selenide.org/2014/04/27/selenide-2.10/) you can find an example of hover() method usage.