# How to click on the RoundTrip radio button within Spicejet website. It gets selected but after few seconds oneway is selected as default

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to click on the **Round Trip** radio button within [SpiceJet](https://www.spicejet.com/) website. It gets selected but after few seconds oneway is selected as default

Below is the code to automate spicejet website as on 11Novemeber 2020. Even if i click on Roundtrip radio button, by default oneway radio button gets selected. How do i resolve this issue?

```
package practice;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Spicejet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='RoundTrip']")).click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTXT']")))
                .click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "//div[@id='glsctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1_CTNR']//table[@id='citydropdown']//li/a[@value='MAA']"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "//div[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_destinationStation1_CTNR']//table[@id='citydropdown']//li/a[@value='BLR']"))
                .click();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the [SpiceJet](https://www.spicejet.com/) web application needs some longer time to to attain `document.readyState` as **`complete`**.

So to `click()` on the [radiobutton](/questions/tagged/radiobutton) associated with the text **Round Trip** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("table.tblTrip input[value='RoundTrip']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//table[@class='tblTrip']//input[@value='RoundTrip']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Spicejet_RoundTrip]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Unable to select depart date in https://spicejet.com through Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039454/unable-to-select-depart-date-in-https-spicejet-com-through-selenium-and-java/53039936#53039936)
- [How to perform multiple actions and click on the link with text as Member Login on the url http://www.spicejet.com/ through selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033243/how-to-perform-multiple-actions-and-click-on-the-link-with-text-as-member-login/52038396#52038396)